# Problems with wx.ListCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Here is a snippet

```
    self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(self, size=(-1,100),
                     style=wx.LC_ICON|wx.LC_ALIGN_LEFT
                     )
    il = wx.ImageList(16,16,True)
    png = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_FILE_OPEN,wx.ART_OTHER, (16,16))
    il.Add(png)
    self.list_ctrl.AssignImageList(il,wx.IMAGE_LIST_NORMAL)


    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)

    self.list_ctrl.InsertImageStringItem(0,"1",0)
    self.list_ctrl.InsertImageStringItem(1,"2",0)
```

My problem is that the icons appear to the top of the text which should not happen because I put `wx.LC_ALIGN_LEFT` in the style. I would like the icons to appear left of the text.

Another problem is that, I want one element per row. In my code it is almost like one element per column.

Can anyone help me with any of these problems?
Thanks.

Comment: I see a problem you don't. You need to store `il` somewhere.

Comment: What about "il = wx.ImageList(16,16,True)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the wxPython demo for the ListCtrl, it looks like they use SetImageList() instead of AssignImageList(). Not sure what the difference is though. I don't see where you're inserting any text though. You'd need to use SetStringItem to put text in the other columns from what I can see.

EDIT: Code from wxPython Demo package, ListCtrl demo:

```
self.il = wx.ImageList(16, 16)

self.idx1 = self.il.Add(images.Smiles.GetBitmap())
self.sm_up = self.il.Add(images.SmallUpArrow.GetBitmap())
self.sm_dn = self.il.Add(images.SmallDnArrow.GetBitmap())
```

And then we add data / images to the widget

```
def PopulateList(self):
    if 0:
        # for normal, simple columns, you can add them like this:
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, "Artist")
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, "Title", wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT)
        self.list.InsertColumn(2, "Genre")
    else:
        # but since we want images on the column header we have to do it the hard way:
        info = wx.ListItem()
        info.m_mask = wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT | wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE | wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT
        info.m_image = -1
        info.m_format = 0
        info.m_text = "Artist"
        self.list.InsertColumnInfo(0, info)

        info.m_format = wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT
        info.m_text = "Title"
        self.list.InsertColumnInfo(1, info)

        info.m_format = 0
        info.m_text = "Genre"
        self.list.InsertColumnInfo(2, info)

    items = musicdata.items()
    for key, data in items:
        index = self.list.InsertImageStringItem(sys.maxint, data[0], self.idx1)
        self.list.SetStringItem(index, 1, data[1])
        self.list.SetStringItem(index, 2, data[2])
        self.list.SetItemData(index, key)
```

Comment: self.list_ctrl.InsertImageStringItem(0,"1",0)   I am calling them numbers, "1" and "2"

Comment: When I use SetImageList instead, the pictures dispensary.

Comment: InsertImageStringItem(index, label, imageIndex). Did you even look at the demo? It shows exactly how to do it. I'll copy and paste some of the relevant code into my answer

Comment: I wasn't being mean. I just want to make sure that you're actively learning and not just asking questions. There are a lot of people on here who won't Google or even try to code up an answer before asking a question. I apologize if I offended you.